# Looking for proper terms to differentiate profits

Tags: profitability

Imagine you’ve invested $1000 into 10 different stocks ($100 for each).
One of them grown +50% and you sold it.
+50% is ROI, right?
And 50% from $100 = $50 which is 5% of the total stack size.
What’s the right term for this +5% indicator?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the investment is on 10 different stocks?

Comment: @Kannan yes, 10 different stocks.

Comment: You would call it something like “contribution”; because that is what it does, it contributes with 5% to the total portfolio return.

Comment: @ssn nice suggestion, thanks! it could be CTP (Contribution to Portfolio)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What is the context that you would need this?  Making up new terms is not helpful, CTP and ROP are meaningless.  ROI is an industry standard, known piece of jargon.  You can have 50% ROI on this position and 5% ROI on your portfolio, both are ROI.

Comment: @quid I need to name two columns in my report. First is ROI from single trade and second is ROI% of that single trade in terms of whole trading stack.

Comment: Both are ROI.  Your second portfolio based ROI will need a footnote because that's a really unusual thing to track.  Specific trade result return based on whole portfolio cost isn't really meaningful.  Typically you want to know how you did in a trade, then you want to know how your whole portfolio is doing, how this one trade did against your whole portfolio would be an unusual thing to look at it's like assuming you used all your portfolio assets to take that specific relatively small position and that's not what happened anyway.

Comment: @quid I have to clarify things a bit. It’s not about single trade, but a position in specific asset. I may increase or decrease some positions and my tool automatically calculates average buy price and shows two ROI columns for each asset. E.g. I bought XXX, YYY and ZZZ for 20%, 30% and 50% (respectively) of my trading stack. And when ZZZ is up 20% I also like to see +10% increase of my portfolio value in that row to visually estimate position performance. Hope I made it clear. And thank you for your thoughts! 

Comment: So, if you have 10 positions in various things, you have say, 1 share of Apple, for $200, the rest of your positions are currently valued at $800, leaving you with a total portfolio value of $1,000; your apple position is 20% of your portfolio (200/1000).  Apple goes up to $210, a 5% increase, and all other positions remain the same, Apple is now 21% of your account (210/1000).  You have a column that you want to show +1%, it was 20% of your portfolio, now it's 21% of your portfolio?  Separately, "trading stack" is not a thing, you have a portfolio or account.

Comment: @quid Yes, exactly. I have a column for each asset showing what ROI contribution that asset made for the whole portfolio.

Comment: I think we're having a failure to communicate.  What math is showing up in your column?

Comment: @quid First column: (CURRENT_ASSET_PRICE – AVG_BUY_PRICE) / AVG_BUY_PRICE * 100
Second column: (FIRST_COLUMN * POS_PERCENT_OF_PORTFOLIO / 100)
Where POS_PERCENT_OF_PORTFOLIO is position's % of total portfolio value (like 20% for that 1 share of Apple for $200 with total portfolio value of $1000)

Answer (score 1):

Return on Investment - ROI

The first one is your ROI for an individual stock.

The second one is your ROI for the whole portfolio, or for your account.

Comment: @Sergey ROI is the standard term. Investment can mean any investment, including either a single stock or a portfolio, so there's no reason to introduce a different term to distinguish the two.

Comment: @DStanley Buy I have to name fields somehow in the report ‍♂️

Comment: @Sergey "Portfolio ROI", if you must

Comment: @Sergey - I don't think what you are trying to do will end up meaning very much in the end - what will it tell you about the performance of your portfolio? A better way is to analyse your positions in terms of risk and in terms of expectancy. Read "Trade your way to financial freedom" by Van Tharp if you want to learn more.